# zip function is returning duplicates

Tags: python, python-2.7

Currently my list is:

```
[[(881, 886), ('Twilight Sparkle', 'Rainbow Dash')],
 [(883, 885), ('Applejack', 'Rarity')], 

[(887, 884), ('Princess Celestia', 'Pinkie Pie')],

 [(888, 882), ('Princess Luna', 'Fluttershy')]]
```

I want it instead to have the format:

```
   [(pid1, pname1, pid2, pname2),

 (pid3, pname3, pid4, pname4), 

(pid5, pname5, pid6, pname6), 

(pid7, pname7, pid8, pname8)]
```

So that it is player1, name 1, player2, name 2

Is it better to do it that in the previous zip function and zip it a different way or manipulate the list now.

I thought to do it

```
temp = x[1]
x[1] = x[2]
x[2] = x[3]
```

But I'm not sure how to do it.

This is the zip function:

```
for i in range(0,length, 2):
    pairs =zip(list[i],list[i+1])
```

Prior to zipping it was in this format:

```
[(881, 'Twilight Sparkle'), (886, 'Rainbow Dash'),
 (883, 'Applejack'), (885, 'Rarity'), 
(887, 'Princess Celestia'), (884, 'Pinkie Pie'),
 (888, 'Princess Luna'), (882, 'Fluttershy')]
```

Is there a way to change the zip function so that it puts the first two in a list, then the second two, and so on but maintains the order of id, name, id, name rather than combining the id and name?

And I want it to be in the format:

```
[(881, 'Twilight Sparkle',886, 'Rainbow Dash'),
 (883, 'Applejack',885, 'Rarity'), 
(887, 'Princess Celestia', 884, 'Pinkie Pie'),
 (888, 'Princess Luna', 882, 'Fluttershy')]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you don't want to zip at all, you just want to concatenate pairs of tuples:

```
players = [(881, 'Twilight Sparkle'), (886, 'Rainbow Dash'),
           (883, 'Applejack'), (885, 'Rarity'),
           (887, 'Princess Celestia'), (884, 'Pinkie Pie'),
           (888, 'Princess Luna'), (882, 'Fluttershy')]
pairs = [players[i] + players[i + 1] for i in range(0, len(players), 2)]
for pair in pairs:
    print(pair)
```

Output:

```
(881, 'Twilight Sparkle', 886, 'Rainbow Dash')
(883, 'Applejack', 885, 'Rarity')
(887, 'Princess Celestia', 884, 'Pinkie Pie')
(888, 'Princess Luna', 882, 'Fluttershy')
```

Comment: Thanks this worked and also was understandable for me. I also appreciate that it was very similar to what I was trying to do rather than something completely different.

Answer (score 3):

You may use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) with [`itertools.chain()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) along with *list comprehension* as:

```
from itertools import chain

[tuple(chain(*zip(*item))) for item in my_list]
```

which returns:

```
[(881, 'Twilight Sparkle', 886, 'Rainbow Dash'), 
(883, 'Applejack', 885, 'Rarity'), 
(887, 'Princess Celestia', 884, 'Pinkie Pie'), 
(888, 'Princess Luna', 882, 'Fluttershy')]
```

where `my_list` is the initial list mentioned in the question

Comment: This looks very similar to what another person suggested but for some reason. It didn't work for me. I was getting an error about iterable. Thanks for the suggestion though. I'm glad to have learned about itertools.chain()

Comment: @John You might not imported the chain. You have to do `from itertools import chain`

Answer (score 1):

List comprehensions would probably be a better approach here:

```
[(item[0][0], item[1][0], item[0][1], item[1][1]) for item in l]
```

---

So for your example

```
players = [[(881, 886), ('Twilight Sparkle', 'Rainbow Dash')],
           [(883, 885), ('Applejack', 'Rarity')], 
           [(887, 884), ('Princess Celestia', 'Pinkie Pie')],
           [(888, 882), ('Princess Luna', 'Fluttershy')]]
```

you would get

```
players_reformatted = [(item[0][0], item[1][0], item[0][1], item[1][1]) for item in players]
```

which gives

```
[(881, 'Twilight Sparkle', 886, 'Rainbow Dash'), 
 (883, 'Applejack', 885, 'Rarity'), 
 (887, 'Princess Celestia', 884, 'Pinkie Pie'), 
 (888, 'Princess Luna', 882, 'Fluttershy')]
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that instead of zipping them.

Comment: This didn't seem to be work because I got TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__' But thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it with a nice little comprehension:

```
>>> r = [sum(zip(*sub), ()) for sub in l]
```

Where you unpack the contents in `zip` with `zip(*sub)` and then flatten the nested tuple created with `sum(iterable, ())`.

This yields:

```
>>> print(r)
[(881, 'Twilight Sparkle', 886, 'Rainbow Dash'),
 (883, 'Applejack', 885, 'Rarity'),
 (887, 'Princess Celestia', 884, 'Pinkie Pie'),
 (888, 'Princess Luna', 882, 'Fluttershy')]
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But this doesn't seem to work. I'm getting TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration I'm not sure if it's because I'm using Python 2.7?